# How to copy a dll from a library into the executable output directory in cmake?

Tags: cmake

My `CMakeLists.txt` creates several libraries using `add_library(MyLib SHARED ${files})` the resulting libraries end up in `<root>/build/libs/MyLib/[Debug|Release]/`
where root is the directory where the main `CMakeLists.txt` is.

How can I copy `MyLib.dll` to the directory where `add_executable` puts the .exe file in CMake? Note that it is important that the .dll copied is the one under Debug or Release depending the build type. Is this possible?

```
root/
|_ build/
|  |_ Debug/
|  |  |_ MyApp.exe
|  |  |_ MyLibd.dll (copied from MyLib/Debug)
|  |_ Release/
|  |  |_ MyApp.exe
|  |  |_ MyLib.dll (copied from MyLib/Release)
|  |_ libs/
|     |_ MyLib/
|        |_ Debug/
|        |  |_ MyLibd.dll
|        |_ Release/
|           |_ MyLib.dll
|_ libs/
|  |_ MyLib/
|     |_ MyLib.cpp
|     |_ MyLib.hpp
|     |_ CMakeLists.txt
|_ CMakeLists
```

Comment: Is there a way to save into a variable the path where the library was created? Say, set (MyLibPath <MyLib.dll-path>) then I could use that in a custom_command, maybe?

Comment: You might want to use install: http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/install.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will recommend you to use the following lines to put all generated `.lib/.dll/.exe` into given folder no matter what build mode (debug or release, x86 or x64) is:

```
set( CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY -some-folder- )
set( CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY -some-folder- )
set( CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY -some-folder- )
```

**Updated:** With this, you can link them by directly using

```
target_link_libraries(app *.lib)
```

Also, you don't need to any copying.

Comment: So I can set those and the resulting dlls (either debug or release) will be there. Then, when liking the application I can do target_link_libraries(app <somefolder>/*.lib) and finally use a custom_command to copy the dlls into $(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY) ? Something along those lines?